# Mocking DbSet<T>.FromSqlRaw in EF Core 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

On of the repository methods happens to use `FromSqlRaw` to fetch the data from SQL Server via a stored procedure.

I am trying to write unit test around it but no luck so far.

This is a sample snippet of how far I got

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var context = new Mock<IMyDbContext>();
var dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<MyEntity>>();
            
var data = fixture.Build<MyEntity>().CreateMany().AsQueryable();
dbSet.As<IQueryable<MyEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
dbSet.As<IQueryable<MyEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
dbSet.As<IQueryable<MyEntity>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
dbSet.As<IQueryable<MyEntity>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());
context.Setup(c => c.Set<MyEntity>()).Returns(dbSet.Object);

var repository = new MyRepository(context.Object);
 
var result = await repository.GetData();
```

Bit I got stuck with the following exception

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryRootExpression'

The project uses EF Core 5.

Any idea how to solve this cast exception?

Comment: A DbSet is not an IQueryable, it implements it. `FromSqlRaw` isn't using the `Set<>()\` method either, it's using the `DbSet` properties and configured entities *to map the results only*.  `Set()` is used *very* infrequently as it doesn't offer anything the properties don't.  It can't even be used if the entities aren't configured. The query is passed from `FromSqlRaw` directly to the database. The code you posted is mocking the wrong things.

Comment: Are you trying to implement the "generic" repository *anti*pattern on top of the higher-level EF Core model? EF Core doesn't need a "generic" repository, as the DbSet class is *already* a repository. A DbContext is *already* a Unit-of-Work involving multiple entity types

Answer (score 0):

Don't mock IQueryable--you're just asking for a world of pain. Use a mock repository (possibly backed by an in-memory DbContext) to unit test consuming classes. Add some integration tests to verify your real repository implementation.

See [Testing code that uses EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/testing/) in the docs for more details.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with the question's code. Instead of creating or mocking an actual DbContext, it tries to mock the `Set()` method that's not used by `FromSqlRaw` at all

Comment: I managed to write a workaround for the unit est by seeding the data to in-memory dbcontext and executing FromSqlRaw against this dbcontext instance. The problem how ever was with models bound to view. You cannot seed the entity if it does not have primary key. Solved it by injecting environment to the configuration and using a condition to define primary key if in unit test. Will share the sample snippet.

Comment: @DejanStojanović please share your snippet